# Importing KMLs to a geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, kml, esri-geodatabase

I've got a folder into which people will dump KML files, and a need to import them into a Feature Class (or more rather, three feature classes eventually - one for points, one for lines, one for polygons) and am having a bit of trouble with the formatting.

My example validates, but on running comes back with the message:

```
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000349: The input parameter is not a Table View
Failed to execute (Append).
```

I'm unsure what I need to do. I do know that everything is being converted to a file geodb earlier on in the progress (which I'd prefer to not do, but if it's there) which I could also get values from, but when I've tried this I get an error indicating that the geometry types aren't the same.

[image]

I'm happy to do this in either ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap, or ArcCatalog (or any other product I may have access to).

Comment: It's a bit hard to say as the picture of the model reveals nothing about the parameters; KML to layer creates a group layer. What is Select Data - POINTS?  it works but the data type of Points is unknown, perhaps use %OutputFileGeodatabase%\Placemarks\Points instead of the output layer which is likely to be a group layer which wouldn't be liked by Append but be sure to use Exists first https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/if-data-exists.htm before trying to append or you model will fall over if there are no points generated.

Comment: @MichaelStimson has the answer (you need to use the actual feature class or layer). The error is saying the input you're providing is not valid. (The input you're making use of is the layer file, although select would be the right approach, what is coming out of select is not)